# Can I get a controller to show up in the url under a different name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-routing

I have a controller called "Pages". Can I make it show up in the url bar under a different name? For example, when I render the 'show' template, it shows up under this url: `localhost:3000/pages/:id`. Could I make it show up as `localhost:3000/people/:id`? I only care about the 'show' url; the other urls aren't that important.

**routes.rb**

```
get "pages/results"
get "pages/index" => "pages#index", as: "index_page"
resources :pages do
  resources :categories
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this your routes:

```
get '/people/:id', to: 'pages#show'
```

And remove the old show route from the resource:

```
resources :pages, only: [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :delete] do
  resources :categories
end
```

See: [Rails guides about rounting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use like this:

```
 get '/pages/:id' => "pages#show", path: 'people/:id'
```

This way you can access particular show page in the browser.
Hope this helps you.